# error: when i try to add <form tag

Tags: jquery, html, validation

below is my html form and i dont get any error if i dont have a `<form` tag, so i add a form tag like this:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="post" action="">
```

get this error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'first_name' is undefined
```

when i try to read the value of a text box:

```
First Name:
<input id="first_name" class=" text hasCorners required" maxlength="200" 
name="first_name"   />

function PostData() {
        var _firstName = first_name.value;
        ......
        ......

 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnRegister').click(function () {
                PostData();
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var _firstName = $('#first_name').val();
```

Comment: even if i use jquery i have to use document.getElementById('first_name') ?

Comment: @RedFilter: With jQuery it needs too be `$('#first_name').val()`.

Comment: if i use $('#first_name').value; i get undefined

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to specify the form element's ID first:

```
commentForm.first_name.value;
```

Not sure why though.

---

**EDIT:** To clarify, this resolves the IE issue with the technique you were using. As @bobince noted in the comment below, accessing IDs as global properties is not safe unless you're targeting specific browsers.

Based on the code in your question and your comment under another answer, it appears that you already know how to select by ID using jQuery and `getElementById`.

Comment: This is still relying on IE/Opera making ID/named element available as global variables, which is a bad idea.

Comment: @bobince - Agreed. Just giving a solution to the IE issue based on the technique being used, since OP already knows how to select by ID using jQuery and `document.getElementById`.